# Rails jquery newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am learning jquery and understand how to link js.erb files to controller actions and have them work.

I am unable to determine how to get a button that is not linked to a controller action to execute some jquery commands.

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for([commentable, Comment.new], remote: true, html: { class: "comment-form", id: "comment-form-#{commentable.id}" }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a comment...", rows: 3, minlength: 10, maxlength: 1000 %>
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Post comment</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
<% end %>
```

This form is displayed using jquery. I would like the "Cancel" button to simply remove the form.

I have created a file called activities.js and in it I have however there is no response from the button at all.

```
$(this).click(function() {
  alert('Hooray!');
});
```

Comment: I strongly reccomend some jquery tutorial first, otherwise you might get confused ery quickly: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: what is `this` in your code? could you post larger snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `id` to the button to use it for selection in `onclick()` event, code below :

**HTML :**

```
 <button id="cancel_comment" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

**JS :**

```
 //Handling click in button
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cancel_comment").click(function() {
       $(this).parents('form').remove(); //removing the parent form
    });
});
```

Be sure you are using `$(document).ready()` .

Comment: This is similar to what I tried previously however I do not think my activity.js file is being loaded correctly as even with the correct code there is zero response from the button. (Yes I did update the button id to "cancel_comment")

Comment: Not sure if this helps but, when I click to add to make the form appear I can submit etc and all works correctly however when I view the page source the form is not listed...?

Comment: is your form is added dynamicly with javascript ??

Comment: try to add just a an `alert()` in your **activity.js** to be sure if it's loaded or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like the "Cancel" button to simply remove the form.

You may do so by using [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$(".btn-default").on("click", function() {

    $(this).closest("form").remove();
});
```